# How Ola Hallengrens Index maintenance scripts handles columnstore indexes?

Tags: sql-server, ola-hallengren, columnstore

I'd like to know how Ola's script handles columnstore indexes. Couln't find any information about that, only in the version history it was mentioned that script does have a support.

My experience is that script didn't do anything to fragmented columnstore index. Is that by design?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ola Hallengren's solution doesn't support Columnstore indexes for now.

There is an outstanding feature request on his Github that hasn't been closed as wontfix so you might want to keep an eye on that: [ColumnStore Support for Index Maintenance #71](https://github.com/olahallengren/sql-server-maintenance-solution/issues/71)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider using Niko's excellect [columnstore index scripts](https://github.com/NikoNeugebauer/CISL), particularly `cstore_doMaintenance.sql`, to maintain columnstore indexes.